# Is there a simple one-liner to split and join a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `string` which looks likes this:

`obj.property1.property2`

I want the `string` to become

`[obj][property1][property2]`

Currently I use a split and later on a `for` loop to join each other. But I was wondering if there was a more simpler method for doing this, perhaps with using `split()` and `join()` toghether. I can't figure out how however.

**Currently using:**

```js
var string = "obj.property1.property2";
var array = string.split(".");
var output = "";

for(var i = 0;i < array.length;i++) {
    output += "[" + array[i] + "]";
};

console.log(output);
```

Comment: what about `var test = "[" + string.split(".").join("][") + "]"`

Comment: @Pete Yes, that works. Thanks :)

Comment: John's answer would be better

Comment: @pete Thanks, was wondering which of the awnsers I should use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using replace with the RegEx global option to replace all instances of '.' with back to back braces, then stick an opening and closing brace on the end like this.

```js
var str ="obj.property1.property2"
console.log("["+str.replace(/\./g,"][")+"]")
```

Comment: Nice more performant than a split join too - https://jsperf.com/replace-vs-split-join-vs-replaceall/23

Comment: Hm, difficult to choose the awnser. Both work, I wonder which of the awnser if best to use .. :)

Comment: Running the JSPerf tests on my system (Chome 61/Windows 10) the split/join option is actually faster (~11%) except where you are using a static regex created before running the loops.

Comment: After making my own test I am not sure which is likely to run quicker. Although I imagine the time take to run the tests will far exceed any execution benefit over the lifetime of your code! https://jsperf.com/replace-in-string-vs-split-and-join/1

Comment: Replace is faster when I test it.

Answer (score 2):

```
'['+string.split('.').join('][')+']'
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But will be using john's awnser, as suggested by @Pete.